# VTK install error cannot find libvtkCommonCore-6.3.so.1

Tags: cmake, installation, vtk, make-install

I'm trying to install VTK but I'm getting the following error

```
 CMake Error at Common/Core/cmake_install.cmake:47 (file):
    file INSTALL cannot find
  "/home/VTK-6.3.0/VTKBuild/lib/libvtkCommonCore-6.3.so.1".
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:100 (include)
```

These are the steps I followed

```
    cd VTKBuild
    cmake ..\
    -D"CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/VTK-6.3.0/VTKBuild" 
    make 
    make install
```

Can anyone point me to what might be going wrong

Comment: Does the mentioned shared library exist in the path as mentioned in the error message? Are you trying to build and install into the same directory? Have you tried installing into a different directory, which is neither a subdir of the build dir nor vice versa?

Comment: No, Ill give it a try and update you. Thanks!

Comment: @Lily so have you found your error? Does it work now?

Comment: @LBes Yes, I had to turn off shared library

Comment: @Lily please post your solution and mark it as accepted then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to turn off shared library option, these are the configuration I used to build VTK

```
mkdir VTKBuild
cd VTKBuild
cmake ..\
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/VTK-6.3.0/VTKBuild \
 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF \
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
 -DVTK_USE_SYSTEM_ZLIB:BOOL=ON


 make 
 make install
```